# Is there a DorisSqlDialect for calcite?

Tags: apache-calcite, apache-doris

I am converting standard SQL to doris SQL to support data structures such as bitmap, hll and aggregation methods such as bitmap_union and hll_union. Is there already written DorisSqlDialect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a Doris dialect for Apache Calcite. There is, however, a [feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-5725) logged that may (depending on contributions) be fixed in future.

Also note in Calcite, SQL functions are orthogonal to dialects. (You could, say, run in the Spark dialect and have the set of functions compatible with Postgres.)

If you have a list of missing functions, you could log them as a feature request. Some of these functions might already exist with different names; for example Doris's `BIT_UNION` function sounds similar to the [existing `BIT_OR` aggregate function](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-3782).